# Safety Data Sheets

Tags: labor, occupational-safety-and-health-act

I am looking to see if there is an api that returns the SDS information for a given pesticide product.

For example, many pesticides have a label with the active ingredients used for managing the pest.  However, there are often other ingredients that are listed on the pesticide label as other, but the SDS has detailed information on them.

Does this data exist in one of your databased that can be queried with an API?

Thanks
Dave